# Center part of a column by decimal point

Tags: tables, siunitx, alignment, dcolumn

I'm really struggling with a table where I would like the labels centered, but the values centered by decimal point. I tried a variety of methods that all failed miserably. Here is the most functional version I have at the moment (where the middle columns are just centered).

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\begin{tabular}{rcccl}
\hline \addlinespace
\ch{Zn_{$x$}H_{$y$}VPO4F}           & Phase 1    & Phase 2       & Phase 3       &     \\ \addlinespace \hline \addlinespace
space group:     & $P\bar1$ (No. 2) & $C2/c$ (No. 15) & $C2/c$ (No. 15) &     \\
\textit{a} =             & 5.188(4)   & 7.327(3)      & 7.169(1)      &  Å  \\
\textit{b} =              & 5.255(2)   & 7.952(2)      & 7.085(3)      & Å   \\
\textit{c} =              & 7.391(2)   & 7.441(7)      & 7.183(4)      & Å   \\
$\alpha$ =          & 111.65(6)  & 90.0          & 90.0          & ° \\
$\beta$ =           & 111.71(8)  & 118.17(1)     & 117.44(2)     & ° \\
$\gamma$ =          & 82.41(5)   & 90.0          & 90.0          & ° \\
\textit{V} =              & 174.0(3)   & 382.2(1)      & 323.8(2)      & Å$^3$  \\
Bragg \textit{R}-factor = & 0.99       & 0.72          & 0.91          &     \\ \addlinespace \hline \addlinespace
\multicolumn{5}{c}{Global weighted $\chi^2$ = 4.83}                     \\ \addlinespace \hline
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:LeBail}
\end{table}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Could you edit your code to begin with your `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}` , a [Minimal Working Example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) please. It makes copy and pasting easier when the code can be compiled and also we do not need to guess what commands or packages you are using. For example, people might not know that `\ch` comes from the `chemmacros` package (I'm assuming you are using that anyway)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't provide the full working example. Please, next time include required components for the MWE. I had to guess a package for chemical formula.

As to the table, `siunitx` and the `S`-column-type can format numbers according to settings, e.g. a decimal marker. There's a [manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx), which you probably should get familiar with. Make sure when you set a column as `S`, any non-numeric content is wrapped inside `{}`.

Also, I would suggest to use rules defined in `booktabs`, which add spacing, so all instances of `\addlinespace` can be avoided. You can alter top and bottom gaps by changing values of `\aboverulesep` and `\belowrulesep`.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\setlength\aboverulesep{5pt}
\setlength\belowrulesep{6pt}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
  \centering
  \caption{My caption}
  \begin{tabular}{
    r *3{S[table-format=3.3]}
    l}
    \toprule
    \ch{Zn_{$x$}H_{$y$}VPO4F} & {Phase 1}          & {Phase 2}         & {Phase 3}         &   \\ \midrule
    space group:              & {$P\bar1$ (No. 2)} & {$C2/c$ (No. 15)} & {$C2/c$ (No. 15)} &   \\
    \textit{a} =              & 5.188(4)           & 7.327(3)          & 7.169(1)          & Å \\
    \textit{b} =              & 5.255(2)           & 7.952(2)          & 7.085(3)          & Å \\
    \textit{c} =              & 7.391(2)           & 7.441(7)          & 7.183(4)          & Å \\
    $\alpha$ =                & 111.65(6)          & 90.0              & 90.0              & ° \\
    $\beta$ =                 & 111.71(8)          & 118.17(1)         & 117.44(2)         & ° \\
    $\gamma$ =                & 82.41(5)           & 90.0              & 90.0              & ° \\
    \textit{V} =              & 174.0(3)           & 382.2(1)          & 323.8(2)          & Å$^3$ \\
    Bragg \textit{R}-factor = & 0.99               & 0.72              & 0.91              & \\ \midrule
    \multicolumn{5}{c}{Global weighted $\chi^2$ = 4.83}                     \\ \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \label{tab:LeBail}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Use `siunitx`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx,caption}
\usepackage{chemformula}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{tab:LeBail}

\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  l
  *{3}{S[table-format=3.3(1)]}
  c
  @{}
}
\toprule
\ch{Zn_{$x$}H_{$y$}VPO4F} & {Phase 1} & {Phase 2} & {Phase 3} & \\
\midrule
space group: & {$P\bar1$ (No.\ 2)} & {$C2/c$ (No.\ 15)} & {$C2/c$ (No.\ 15)} &   \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-2} \cmidrule(lr){3-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-4}
$a$          &   5.188(4)          &   7.327(3)         &   7.169(1)         & Å \\
$b$          &   5.255(2)          &   7.952(2)         &   7.085(3)         & Å \\
$c$          &   7.391(2)          &   7.441(7)         &   7.183(4)         & Å \\
$\alpha$     & 111.65(6)           &  90.0              &  90.0              & ° \\
$\beta$      & 111.71(8)           & 118.17(1)          & 117.44(2)          & ° \\
$\gamma$     &  82.41(5)           &  90.0              &  90.0              & ° \\
$V$          & 174.0(3)            & 382.2(1)           & 323.8(2)           & Å$^3$ \\
\midrule
Bragg $R$-factor & {0.99} & {0.72} & {0.91} & \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{5}{@{}l@{}}{Global weighted $\chi^2$ = 4.83} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]